# Images are not storing in Database using multer

Tags: node.js, mongodb, multer

I am trying to store image in local folder and save image name in mongodb using `multer` with the below code.

```
var uploadDir=__dirname+ '/assets/images';
var images='.jpg';
var storage=multer.diskStorage({
  destination:function(req, file, cb){
    cb(null, uploadDir);
  },
  filename:function(req, file, cb){
    console.log(file);
    image=Date.now()+images;
    callback(null, images);
  }
});
var upload=multer({storage:storage}).single('img');
```

But its not storing image in local folder and only its saving `.jpg` string in image field in mongodb. I think the problem is that `filename:` method is not working. Please review it and help me to find the solution.

Thanks,

Comment: How do you register the multer middleware in your route? Can you provide this piece of code as well?

Comment: `apiRoutes.post('/adcreate',upload ,function(req, res, next){
 /*---- insert data code--*/
})`

Comment: Just posted an answer below. This middleware is registered properly and the error is in the definition of your multer config.

Comment: @Svabael above posted code is working fine in my last app. But its not working in my current application. I am not able to find the error. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in the multer filename configuration. You were using the images variable in there and that's why wasn't storing the image in the right path and only with the .jpg name. It is a good idea to define the `var image` as var, otherwise will be defined in the global namespace with side effects that you can not predict. This should work:

```
var uploadDir=__dirname+ '/assets/images';
var images='.jpg';
var storage=multer.diskStorage({
  destination:function(req, file, cb){
    cb(null, uploadDir);
  },
  filename:function(req, file, cb){
    console.log(file);
    var image=Date.now()+images;
    callback(null, image);
  }
});
```

Comment: @SaurabhSharma what is the error? You didn't post an error before. You just said that the images are not saved with the proper name and in the proper directory. Do you have this result yet?

Comment: yeah .... there is no any error showing on my console. I posted this Question because I am not able to store image in folder and image name in mongodb

Comment: @SaurabhSharma the code snippet that you've posted will not save something in mongo. It will just save it in the directory that you 've specified here: `var uploadDir=__dirname+ '/assets/images';`

Comment: I know... above code snippet will not save image name in DB. but I will use `image` variable to save it on DB. like as `apiRoutes.post('/adcreate',upload ,function(req, res, next){
  var ad=new admodel({image:image}) ;
    ad.save(function(err, data){
          if(err){
            return res.json({success:false, msg:'Ad not Posted'});
          }else{
            res.json({succes:true, msg:'Successfully ad Posted'});
          }
     });
});`

Comment: This line is wrong `var ad=new admodel({image:image}) ;`. What is the `image` variable? You need to retrieve the data from req.file. The image variable it is defined in the global context and has nothing to do with your request

Comment: when image will upload the `filename` contains variable `image` with a string which  rewrites on image and that same variable i.e `image` I am storing it on DB